# How to distinct debian testing package versions from stable ones by cli/script?

Tags: debian, package-management, testing

How to distinct debian testing package version from stable packages by cli/script?
Debian has Testing source list and DB in order to get some Testing versions downloaded only, but how to ensure/distinct one was installed because it's owned by the Stable and one by Testing
e.g.

```
$ sudo apt depends -i libopenimageio2.2
libopenimageio2.2
  Depends: libavcodec58 (>= 7:4.2)
    libavcodec-extra58
  Depends: libavformat58 (>= 7:4.1)
  Depends: libavutil56 (>= 7:4.0)
  Depends: libboost-filesystem1.74.0 (>= 1.74.0)
  Depends: libboost-thread1.74.0 (>= 1.74.0)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29)
  Depends: libdcmtk15 (>= 3.6.5)
  Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1)
  Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.0)
  Depends: libgif7 (>= 5.1)
  Depends: libheif1 (>= 1.3.2)
  Depends: libilmbase25 (>= 2.5.3)
  Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1)
  Depends: libopencolorio1v5 (>= 1.1.1~dfsg0)
  Depends: libopencv-core4.5 (>= 4.5.1+dfsg)
  Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.5 (>= 4.5.1+dfsg)
  Depends: libopencv-videoio4.5 (>= 4.5.1+dfsg)
  Depends: libopenexr25 (>= 2.5.3)
  Depends: libopenjp2-7 (>= 2.0.0)
  Depends: libopenvdb7.1
  Depends: libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1)
  Depends: libraw20 (>= 0.16.0)
  Depends: libsquish0
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9)
  Depends: libswscale5 (>= 7:4.0)
  Depends: libtbb2 (>= 2017~U7)
  Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3)
  Depends: libwebp6 (>= 0.5.1)
```

...
of

```
$ sudo apt search libopenimageio2.2/testing

libopenimageio2.2/testing 2.2.10.1+dfsg-1 amd64
```

clearly not doing the comparing on `apt search`  ... of both each one by one for at least 40 such stuffs to work. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by piping the result of `apt depends`  to `apt-cache policy` :

```
apt-cache depends -i libopenimageio2.2 |awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt policy
```

`apt depends -i libopenimageio2.2`

cross refer both one-liner each other

Note: `-i` option and `-cache` apt command category must be used precisely